# How to change the injected download secret steps in Azure DevOps classic release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a classic release pipeline that uses a linked key vault variable group. In the agent phrase log I can see there is a "download secret" task/step that I dont define it explicitly in the task list.

I want to add some other tasks before this pipeline is accessing the key vault, but I didn't see an option to either disable this injected download secret task or adjust its sequence. Anyone has an idea to achieve this?